# Adding additional cycle to my WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have a cursor that goes through a list of table+column names (ordered by table and column name) and produces SQL queries. Part of a query is constructed on each cycle and the whole query is executed when the table name is different from previous cycle's table name (which is saved in a variable).

The problem with this approach is that last row does not trigger the execution part, as there is no new table name after the last row. I have to repeat the whole code for the logic after the loop just to handle the last row and execute last query.

Loop condition is the usual:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 ... <logic> ... <fetch next> END
```

I have tried to change it to:

```
WHILE 1=1 ... <logic> ... IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK ... <fetch next> END
```

which does execute the last query and exits the loop, but the problem with this is that the loop would trigger on empty set, which is bad.

Is there a way to avoid repeating the loop code after the loop in my case? It is a lot of code and hard to maintain.

PS The cursor is necessary, the code is unreadable without it.

Comment: You could alter your query to include a `UNION ALL` with a terminator (dummy data) so your loop always detects a change (and then never process the last row, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic you're looking for is:

```
Declare YourCursor Cursor ...
...

While (1 = 1)
Begin
    Fetch Next From YourCursor Into @C_YourVariables    

    If @@Fetch_Status <> 0 Break

    <Do stuff>
End

Close YourCursor
Deallocate YourCursor
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing, like moving first fetch into the loop itself :) Thanks!